# How can I edit a CSV file with more than 2 million rows

Tags: excel

Really need some quick help with this please.

I have a comma delimited CSV file that holds about 2 millions rows of data (a lot I know but it's the only format I can work with unfortunately). One of the rows has some numbers in it that have lots of decimal places (like 3.908651901). I need to round that entire column - all 2 million rows - to whole integers.

The problem is that when I open it in excel it says something like "only 1 million rows shown". After more investigation I have found out that excel cannot handle more than 1 millions rows at a time.

My question is this: If I select the whole column and round the numbers to integers will that apply to the entire 2 millions rows? Or only the 1 million showing in excel?

Are there any other programs available that can handle 2-2.5 million rows and change the column to whole integers?

Answer (score 0):

Proably the easiest way is to write a little program to do it.  This can be done in any one of many different languages, but since you mention Excel, here's quick and dirty VBA based option, which might suffice for a one off task. This will not be that fast, took about a minute on my hardware. Other options will no doubt be faster...

This only works because the the data never actually touches a worksheet so the million line limit doesn't come into play.

```
Sub RoundCsv()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim csvIn As TextStream
    Dim csvOut As TextStream
    Dim FinePathAndName As String
    Dim FinePathAndNameNew As String
    Dim ln As String
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim RoundColumn As Long

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    FinePathAndName = "C:\Your\Path\And\File\Name.csv"
    FinePathAndNameNew = "C:\Your\Path\And\File\NameNew.csv"
    RoundColumn = 3 '<-- set to the column number to round, count from 0
    Set csvIn = fso.OpenTextFile(FinePathAndName, ForReading, False)
    Set csvOut = fso.CreateTextFile(FinePathAndNameNew, True)

    Do While Not csvIn.AtEndOfStream
        ln = csvIn.ReadLine
        dat = Split(ln, ",")
        dat(RoundColumn) = Round(dat(RoundColumn))
        ln = Join(dat, ",")
        csvOut.WriteLine ln
    Loop

    csvIn.Close
    csvOut.Close
    Set csvIn = Nothing
    Set csvOut = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late here but just had the same issue. After some Googling I found this program called gSplit that can break up a large csv into a multiple smaller files, and also put those smaller pieces back into 1 large file.

You can break up your CSV into half or thirds, format each one, and then reunite them.

PS I am no way affiliated with this product, I just found it and it solved my issue so I figured I would rep it here.

http://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit/